# Can I make desktop-only games using libGDX?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm kinda new to libGDX and I can't quite get why is the Android module necessary in the gdx-setup-ui?
Isn't libGDX used for making desktop games? And is there a way of creating a desktop project avoiding the Android one (having core + desktop only)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to official documentation (and my practice in the past), yes, you can. You'd just delete the android project and all is done. But using Java for desktop-only game development is quite strange, because there's .NET and even open-source implementation of .NET (Mono). With JVM, you cannot achieve good performance especially for games (or it will be VERY hard & dirty), because there is no user-defined value types, all generics can only have reference types as type parameters, etc.

Comment: I disagree that the desktop JVM can't achieve good performance for games.

Comment: Ok. "Good" may not be precise, but you certainly can get better performance and less GC stuttering when using other VMs or native code for same task. (Of course, this is true only if your Java code will hit some performance-related JVM limitations... but good luck trying not to hit them.) And of course, for many games even JVM will be enough. A simple game without much pressure on CPU may not be worth learning another language.

Comment: That I agree with. A first person shooter using JVM would need to cache everything to keep the GC from killing frame rate. Something simpler would be fine.

Comment: But I personally think that learning a new language is almost always good. :P

Comment: I have a hard time believing that .NET would be vastly superior (ie C#) over Java. The issue is native library bindings and GC.

Comment: And don't forget the fact that because it's running on JVM you can use it on Linux or MacOS too. That would not be the case with .NET.

Comment: @sheitan You forgot about Mono.

Answer (score 4):

Checkout [this](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ProjectSetupNew), here you see that you use your core project to put all the non-specific platform code, and the desktop project is the project you run when you want to run for the desktop.

Comment: well, yeah. I've read that all. The question is: can I avoid having Android module and can it be simply deleted without issues?

Comment: You should be able to do that yes.

Comment: Beware that default assets are put into the Android project (because its build tools suck), so if you nuke it you'll want to put the assets in your desktop or core projects.

Comment: Because of what @P.T. is saying, I simply remove the _src_ folder from the build path and leaving the rest intact. However, I _do_ intend to port my game to Android at some point in the far future...

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to move Main.java and contents of /lib folder from the desktop to the core project in order to remove the former. You will need to fiddle with build path settings in order for it to work, but I think it is easier to have one project in this case.